# Removing Executed SQL queries from the report output of Mocha test

Tags: mocha.js

Here is the reporter output:

```
Mitchs-MacBook-Pro:tshirtShop Bugzy$ mocha --exit test/models/product-db.js 
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13


  Product to DB

Executing (default): INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`discounted_price`,`image`,`image_2`,`thumbnail`,`display`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'BLah BLah','\"The Fur Merchants\". Not all the beautiful stained glass in the great cathedrals depicts saints and angels! Lay aside your furs for the summer and wear this beautiful T-shirt!','22.95','17.95','chartres-cathedral.gif','chartres-cathedral-2.gif','chartres-cathedral-thumbnail.gif',1);
ALl properties created corretly
      ✓ can create a new Product and save it to the db (832ms)
Executing (default): SELECT `product_id`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `discounted_price`, `image`, `image_2`, `thumbnail`, `display` FROM `product` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`product_id` = 1;
      ✓ can find the first record (77ms)
      Not-nullable properties give the proper validation errors
        ✓ Error thrown for name
        ✓ Error thrown for description
        ✓ Error thrown for price
        ✓ Error thrown for discounted_price
        ✓ Error thrown for display


  7 passing (932ms)
```

I want to get rid of the Executing  (default) statements. I have gone through all the reporter options but the SQL statements remain.

Comment: is that come from log in the source file? or maybe check the library option that you use to access the db, it could have something that output the sql.

Comment: That is sequelize printing that out. I see similar when writing unit tests when I forget to stub/mock the sequelize in my project.